# Getting computation result from server with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I implemented a form with a set of values, for example a date input that can be increased or decreased stepwise, and some counters that behave in the same fashion.

Every time I manipulate the counters, a function of these inputs is calculated and a result is shown. I have two options:

1. Calculate the result with AngularJS, as the form is manipulated, and recalculate it again, as the data is sent to the server. That means, I need to write the function in Javascript and then again in whatever language I use for the APIs.
2. Ask for the result to the server every time one of these inputs is modified. If the result depends on the status of the database for example, that might be the only viable option.

How do I implement the second option? My tentative approach is:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['form.input1', 'form.input2', 'form.input3'], function() {
    $scope.result = $scope.recalc();
});

$scope.recalc = function() {
    $scope.evaluateRequest += 1;
    $scope.result = null;

    $http.post('/api/recalculation', {evaluate_request: $scope.evaluateRequest, input1: $scope.form.input1, input2: $scope.form.input2, input3: $scope.form.input3}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if ( data['evaluate_request'] != $scope.evaluateRequest )
                return
            $scope.result = data['result'];
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('ERROR');
        });
};
```

That is, is `$watchGroup` the way to go?

Comment: Use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$watchGroupBy` while `$watch` has better functionality in it of watching deep object.

By looking at your code, I think you don't need which value is changed. Only when one of the value of form gets change then you want to call `$scope.recalc()` function.

I'd suggest to use `$watch` which will watch the entire object `form`. Any of the value change, we will calculate the result.

**CODE**

```
$scope.$watch('form', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal != oldVal) { //value change then do calculation.
       $scope.result = $scope.recalc();
    }
},true);
```

Mentioning true will watch whole object (deep variables) getting watch, and any change will call then function and re-calculate the value accordingly.

Hope this could help you. Thanks.